# Moq verify property when method is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am unit testing a wrapper around WebClient. I want to check at the time calling UploadString, the QueryString property is set to a specific value. I don't need to check the QueryString value after the whole method finish.

```
mockedWebClient.Setup(w=>w.UploadString("url2","POST","bodyyy")).Return("response");
mockedWebClient.Setup(w=>w.QueryString).Return(new NameValueCollection());

testibject.SomeMethod();

// Verify method was called 
mockedWebClient.Verify(w=>w.UploadString("url2","POST","bodyyy");
// Also verify QueryString is set at the time UploadString is called???
```

Comment: What is QueryString a property of?

Comment: The WebClient. I'll add the setup for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Callback**

You can use the `Callback` method when using `Setup`. For instance:

```
NameValueCollection queryString = new NameValueCollection();

mockedWebClient.Setup(w=>w.QueryString).Return(queryString);

bool isExpected = false;

mockedWebClient
    .Setup(w=>w.UploadString("url2","POST","bodyyy"))
    .Callback(() => isExpected = queryString["SomeKey"] == "SomeValue")
    .Return("response");

testibject.SomeMethod();

Assert.IsTrue(isExpected);
```